# Parar settimeOut Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom estou fazendo uma função para verificar determinada iteração e se ela passar de x eu pauso o contator, porem não está funcionando, ele continua a aparecer janela de alert, segue meu exemplo abaixo?

```
function verificaComplet(tam, page){
var tentativas = 0,
    maxRange = tam + 5,
    time;
console.log("max Range " + maxRange);
console.log("iteracoes " + iteracoes);
iteracoes = iteracoes + 1;

if(maxRange > iteracoes){
    if(w_variavel == tam){
        activate_page(page);
        desbloqueiTela("#BloqueiaLogin");
    }else{
        time = setTimeout(function () { verificaComplet(tam, page);}, 5000);
    }
}else{
    clearTimeout(time);
    desbloqueiTela("#BloqueiaLogin");
    alert("Tempo de espera escedido, Por favor tente novamente mais tarde.");
}
}
```

A saida do programa ta sendo a seguinte:

```
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 17 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 18 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 19 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 20 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 21 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 22 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 23 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 24 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 25 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 26 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 27 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 28 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 29 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 30 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 31 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 32 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 33 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 34 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 35 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 36 VM2450 main.js:609
max Range 22 VM2450 main.js:608
iteracoes 37 VM2450 main.js:609
```

Comment: poderia postar o codigo do método `desbloqueiTela`? a unica explicação que vejo para este loop, é o `desbloqueiTela` está chamando o `verificaComplet`

Comment: você poderia adicionar a seguinte linha na função `verificaComplet`: `console.log("caller " + (arguments.callee.caller.name || "desconhecido"));`

Comment: P.S: se estiver utilizando `strict mode` use `verificaComplet.caller.name || "desconhecido"` no lugar de `arguments.callee`

Comment: Outra possibilidade é algum método alterar o valor de [ iteracoes ], que é uma variável de escopo externo. E também há a variável [ w_variavel ] que também é de escopo externo.

Comment: P.S.: Consegui que funcionasse neste Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kb7s8eeq/
E mais uma coisa. O clearTimeout que você chama não tem utilidade nenhuma. A variável [ time ] é declarada em cada chamada à função.
Então quando você chama clearTimeout(time) o valor de time é undefined. E o setTimeout é executado apenas uma vez. O setInterval é que se executa continuamente.

Considere as condições para sua função agir corretamente:
  maxRange deve ser maior que iteracoes
    w_variavel deve ser igual à tam
Ambas as condições são avaliadas como "false".

Comment: Mokyn irei testa aqui em produção para ver se ira funcionar

Comment: Galera consegui resolver... O problema estava porque eu tinha um for que fazia a chamada para a função, porem agora funcionou tudo bem.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o problema está no fato de `time` estar declarado dentro de `verificaComplet`.

Isso faz com que, toda vez que é chamado `verificaComplet` dentro do `setTimeout`, uma nova instância seja criada.

Talvez o que resolva o problema é "declarar do lado de fora" da função para que essa variável se torne a referência única para o timeout atual.

Exemplo:

```js
$(function()
{
 uniqueTimeout = (function(){
   // preste atenção nesse escopo
      var time = 0;

          return function (func, delay) {
               clearTimeout(time);
               time = setTimeout(func, delay);
          }
     })();

 var escreve = function(){
      $('body').append('<div>escreveu uma vez?</div>');
 }


 uniqueTimeout(escreve, 1000)
 uniqueTimeout(escreve, 1000)
 uniqueTimeout(escreve, 1000)
 uniqueTimeout(escreve, 1000)
 uniqueTimeout(escreve, 1000)
 uniqueTimeout(escreve, 1000)


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Perceba que, apesar do `setTimeout` lá dentro, a minha função só escreveu 1 vez, pois o `setTimeout` foi limpado.